# Replacing GWT RPC with JBoss Errai

Tags: gwt, errai

I myself haven't tried JBoss Errai at all, but I am thinking of migrating the server-side services of my current GWT project into a new project that will be now treated as a platform.

The services in the currect project that are accessed via RPC can be commonly used with other projects as "base platform."

So, I am thinking of using using JBoss Errai for this scenario. And so, the new "base" platform project will be non-GWT and that Ajax apps built with GWT will just call into this platform for authentication, storage, etc.

Is this a good approach anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project actually runs fine, why would you want to change it? you can instead, integrate the errai framework and when you want to add a new component, you can take advantage of the features of errai ;-)

Comment: JBoss Errai removes a lot of boilerplate code in GWT, it also has this really nice templating